# How can I add a constant factor in Excel cell as output?

Tags: excel

Hi guys I would like to write different words in every excel cell and get the same words but every cell must have a new constant symbol.

Maybe an example will be useful.

I would like to write this:

```
--------INPUT
AAPL
ORCL
TSLA
IMB
MSFT
```

And get into another cells this:

```
--------OUTPUT
,'AAPL'
,'ORCL'
,'TSLA'
,'IMB'
,'MSFT'
```

Is it something possible with excel?

I didn't put an image because this website tells me I'm not allowed, sorry.

Hope anyone can help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 ways : `&` OR `CONCATENATE()`

```
=",'"&A1&"'"
```

OR

```
=CONCATENATE(",'",A1,"'")
```

please if it works in your version of excel.. ( :